# How to toggle a set interval function in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a countdown timer. When I press on the number 31 (run the code) I want the countdown to toggle between start and pause. How to I do that?Another click event on the h1 element would not work.
Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clock').click(start)
});
var seconds = 60;
let interval;
let minutes, id;

function start(e) {
  id = e.target.id;
  minutes = Number(e.target.textContent) - 1;
  interval = setInterval(startTimer, 1000)
  console.log(id)
}

function startTimer() {
  seconds--;
  $(`#${id}`).text(minutes + ' : ' + seconds);
  if (seconds == 0) {
    seconds = 60;
    minutes--;
    if (minutes < 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      alert('time is up');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>My Lab</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="clock">31</h1>
  </div>
</body>
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clock').click(start)
});
var seconds = 60;
let interval = null;
let minutes, id;

function start(e) {
    id = e.target.id;
    if (!minutes) {
        minutes = Number(e.target.textContent) - 1;
    }
    if (interval == null) {
        interval = setInterval(startTimer, 1000)
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
    }
}

function startTimer() {
    seconds--;
    $(`#${id}`).text(minutes + ' : ' + seconds);
    if (seconds == 0) {
        seconds = 60;
        minutes--;
        if (minutes < 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            alert('time is up');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>My Lab</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="clock">31</h1>
  </div>
</body>
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you used `if (!minutes){}`

Comment: `minutes = Number(31) - 1;` when you will pause timer and start again then minutes will be something like this  `minutes = Number(30:59) - 1;` which is equal to `NaN`  (you can not convert `30:59` to number).

Comment: If you are looking for resting timer to original time (31) then set `minutes = null` and `interval = null`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can maintain a flag `isPaused` and check its value in the `setInterval` and toggle its value on every click.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  let isPaused = true;
  let time = 0;
  let countdownTime = 31 * 60 * 1000;

  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (!isPaused) {
      countdownTime -= 1000;
      let min = Math.floor(countdownTime / (60 * 1000));
      let sec = Math.floor((countdownTime - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);

      if (countdownTime <= 0)
        alert("31 min!");
      else
        $('#clock').html(`${min}:${sec}`);
    }
  }, 1000);

  $('#clock').click(function(e) {
    isPaused = !isPaused;
  });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>My Lab</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="clock">31</h1>
  </div>
</body>
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var seconds = 60;
   var interval;
   var minutes, id;

   function countdown(){
      interval = setInterval(function(){
        seconds--;

        if (seconds == 0) {
            seconds = 60;
            minutes--;
            if (minutes < 0) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              alert('time is up');
               $('#clock').text('00:00');
             }
         }
         var sec_out='0'+seconds;
         sec_out=sec_out.substr(sec_out.length-2);   //for 05 or 03 sec...

         var min_out='0'+minutes;
         min_out=min_out.substr(min_out.length-2);   //for 05 or 03 min...

         $('#clock').text(min_out + ':' + sec_out);

      }, 10);    //10 for example change to 1000
    }

  $('#clock').click(function(){
      if(!interval){
             // for start timer
           var this_val=$(this).text();
           var this_val_first=this_val.split(':')[0];
           this_val_first=parseInt(this_val_first,10);
           minutes=this_val_first;
           countdown();
      }else{
             // for stop timer
          clearInterval(interval);
          interval = null;
      }
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


   <div class="container">
    <h1 id="clock" style="cursor:pointer;">31</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your working solution, which is a bit more advanced for me.